# Toggling in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

<script src="C:\Users\rapandey\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.container .text').each(function () {
            if ($(this).height() > 100) {
                $(this).parent().addClass('container-cut').append('<div class="enlarge">... (Show More)</div>');
            }

        });

        $(".enlarge").click(function () {
           // $(this).remove();

            text_height = $(".text").height();

            $(".container").animate({
                height: text_height
            });

            $('.container .text').each(function () {
                if ($(this).height() > 100) {
                    $(this).parent().addClass('container-cut').append('<div class="contract">... (Show Less)</div>');
                }

            });
        });


        $(".contract").click(function () {

            $(".container").animate({
                height: 100
            });

        });
    });
    </script>

<style type="text/css">
   .container{
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #cacaca;
    font-size:12px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px;
}
.container-cut { height: 100px }
.enlarge{
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
    bottom:-1px;
    right:10px;
    width:80px;
    color:blue;
}
  .contract{
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
    bottom:-1px;
    right:10px;
    width:80px;
    color:blue;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So this code part is related to toggle option, where a part of the code will be shown and some part will be hidden with the option of show more. When any one clicks on it the whole contents gets loaded. Finally another link is shown up which is show less. when someone clicks on show less the content again should compress. But I have no clue for some reason contraction of text is not getting called. Contract method is not getting called

Attached is the link for jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rapandey/48HyG/

Show less option is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need event delegation:

```
 $(".container").on('click','.contract',function () {
        $(".container").animate({
            height: 100
        });
 });
```

also do the same for show more option:

```
 $(document).on('click','.enlarge',function () {
   //rest code
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/48HyG/1/)**